# Cloudflare wait time over 20 seconds

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I have been trying to find ways to speed up the load time of my site, so I have turned to CloudFlare to see if I can improve my load time.

My site is thelocalgolfer.com and I host it with hostmonster. I took three consecutive gtMetrix tests w/o cloudflare enabled and then enabled cloudflare ran three
consecutive gtMetrix tests w/ cloudflare enabled. You will see that with
cloudflare enabled it takes on average 21 seconds of wait time on the initial load. I have spent hours on the phone with hostmonster tech support trying to troubleshoot the problem and they said they have exhausted all options on their side.

```
Also to note when cloudflare is enabled one of the errors I have been
getting is 
    Error : cURL error 6: Resolving host timed out: www.thelocalgolfer.com
    in the middle of the page after the page loads. The page still takes about 21 seconds
```

Try it yourself I still have it enabled (for now).

Here are the gtmetrix results with CloudFlare enabled:

```
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.thelocalgolfer.com/C3Yv7xNW
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.thelocalgolfer.com/Y35wcjzO
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.thelocalgolfer.com/x82tUdhH
```

Without Cloudflare enabled:

```
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.thelocalgolfer.com/NevlWuVV
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.thelocalgolfer.com/GDiEPUnG
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.thelocalgolfer.com/CcuvxYdq
```

By the way I have gone back and forth with CloudFlare and they have been less than helpful, they tell me to tweak this option or that option, and they take 24-48 hours to respond.

I am hoping that someone has experience with this issue and can help me out!

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone that runs in to a similar problem, I was running simplepie on my site which was causing a loopback situation where the page was calling an RSS feed on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I actually posted some information in your support ticket relative to the issue. Doing a curl against the www record, with no CloudFlare in the middle, is returning a very large response time.

Comment: Can you please provide steps for how to fix this?  It was not provided in the support ticket.

Comment: I can't provide steps on how to fix it on your server (that would be a hosting issue). I provided the curl information in the ticket that should be helpful with your host.

Note: It seems odd because I don't see the issue on your root domain checking it directly. It only returns that huge response time directly on the www record (when we're not touching it) so it would appear like something is not configured correctly on your server.

Comment: So this was configured through the cPanel of hostmonster using the cloudflare plugin.  Does that help?  Should I try disabling through the cPanel and try to enable through CloudFlare?